# Changing the key in a counter form an integer to a string

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

Please is there a way to change the key in a counter from an interger to a string?

```
Counter({0: 335251, 1: 31430})
```

Comment: Please don't spam tags

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that `Counter` comes from `collections` module. If yes, [`Counter` is just a subclass of `dict`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L534) which means that all `dict` methods are available in `Counter` class as well.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>>
>>> c = Counter({0: 335251, 1: 31430})
>>> {str(key): value for key, value in c.items()}
{'0': 335251, '1': 31430}
>>>
```